# Why does my PAssert not match an item in my PCollection?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a PCollection which I am certain contains:

- "Bob"
- "John"
- "Fred"

However, when I test an assertion that asks if "Bob" is in the PCollection using:

```java
PAssert.that(myPcollection).containsInAnyOrder("Bob")
```

we fail the assertion.  Since "Bob" is in the PCollection, why is it failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `containsInAnyOrder()` function is used to determine that the source PCollection contains *all* the items and not just a subset of the items.  Don't think of this as "Does it contain the elements I listed?" but rather think of it as  "Is this PCollection **completely** made up of all the elements I listed (but in any order)".

Comment: Do we know of any assertion that checks for subset of PCollection?